# How to update view scope bean from another view scope bean?

Tags: jsf-2, dependency-injection

I have view scope search and edit beans which are created by:

```
javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean

javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped
```

When the user makes search and view the search results, he select a result and open it in new window and after the saving changes I want to update the results in search bean, so when I try to get the search bean using any of the following methods:

```
public static <T> T getBean(String beanName) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        return (T) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{" + beanName + "}", Object.class);
    }

public static <T> T getViewScopeBean(String beanName){
  Map<String, Object> viewMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap();
  return (T) viewMap.get(beanName);
}
```

it returns null and can't find the search bean for the second method, and for the first method it creates a new instance of the search bean (although the search page is still opened), when I printed all the values in the map it doesn't contain the search bean. How can I get the search bean?

Comment: @Jaqen H'ghar yes, tried that and it doesn't create new instance but it all the variables in the bean returns default values.

Comment: What version of JSF are you running?

Comment: @Jaqen H'ghar, i open a new window with javascript

Comment: @kolossus version 2.2.2

Comment: Why don't you just transmit the saved changes via the flash scope, to the search bean? Your current approach is counting on a situation where the user won't have more than one window/tab open for that particular page. Not that it would matter anyway: a viewscope exists within the current `FacesContext`. You can't reach across to a different context to get a viewscoped bean that exists there.

Comment: @kolossus, can you please an example of how to accomplish that with flash scope or at least tutorial link for similar solution (i need a place to start from), i never used it before.

Comment: [Try this](http://jugojava.blogspot.com/2011/06/jsf2-flash-scope-example.html). Unfortunately, I'm not too impressed with the flash scope tutorials out there (and Bauke hasn't written one). If you have problems implementing a solution using this link, update your question with your working code and anyone here will be able to help